# How to generate source files from navision webservice with ntlm authentication

Tags: wsimport, navision, ntlm-authentication

I am trying to generate the source files from a Navision web service(NTLM authentication) using wsimport.Below is the command
wsimport -XdisableSSLHostnameVerification -d generated -s source -Xauthfile auth2.txt -keep "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/XXXell/WS/XXXXLimited/Page/XXXXXOrder"

in auth.txt

http[s]://user:password@host:port//

I am unable to generate the source files.Please help with any link or sample which can help

Any quick help will be appriciated....

Answer (score 1):

This thread is pretty old but in case someone pass by I share my experience.

For NTLM you do **not** need file `auth.txt`

**TL;TR**

Use `tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport` and add Java options `"-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=MYDOMAIN" "-Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts"` before if you use Java greater than `1.8.0_181`.

**Long version**

Until Java `1.8.0_181`, NTLM was enabled by default but it's not the case anymore (current version I use is `1.8.0_222`"). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54628051/349228

To be able to use NTLM with `wsimport` tool I had to use the `tools.jar` manually :

`java "-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=MYDOMAIN" "-Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts" -cp %JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport -p "my.target.package.name" -d . -keep -encoding UTF-8 "http://navisionhost:7047/DynamicsNAV110/WS/Test 01/Page/MyPage"`

Key part for NTLM is the 2 java options `"-Dhttp.auth.ntlm.domain=MYDOMAIN" "-Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts"`. The rest is close to the native tool call except we run the Main Java Class from this jar `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar` manually.

Answer (score 0):

just ask the Navision Admin to change the config to use Basic Auth:

[How to: Use an Access Key for SOAP and OData Web Service Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672864(v=nav.90).aspx)

Cheers