# How to provide ntlm authentication while calling any url?

Tags: java, java-8, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a hosted url which authenticates using ntlm (windows Integrated authentication). I am on windows and using java 1.8

```
URL url = new URL("someUrl");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
 int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // read response
            ...
            in.close();
            }else{
            System.out.println("Error while fetching reponse, recieved response code " + responseCode);
            }
```

The above code used to work till java 1.8.0_181
 With subsequent updates it started failing, I have tested with 191 and 201.
The code still works if backported to 181.
I also tried using Authenticator, but it is not invoked (not sure why)
With java's internal logging I could see following message in the logs
*"NegotiateAuthentication: java.io.IOException: Negotiate support not initiated"*
And I get 401

I am expecting any mechanism to help java negotiate on its own for authentication.

Answer (score 18):

In Java release notes it is not mentioned anywhere but there is a change in NTLM authentication implementation.
I have debugged the java code and arrived at following
In java.home/lib there is file net.properties which now mentions following

```
#
# Transparent NTLM HTTP authentication mode on Windows. Transparent authentication
# can be used for the NTLM scheme, where the security credentials based on the
# currently logged in user's name and password can be obtained directly from the
# operating system, without prompting the user. This property has three possible
# values which regulate the behavior as shown below. Other unrecognized values
# are handled the same as 'disabled'. Note, that NTLM is not considered to be a
# strongly secure authentication scheme and care should be taken before enabling
# this mechanism.
#
# Transparent authentication never used.
#jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=disabled
#
# Enabled for all hosts.
#jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts
#
# Enabled for hosts that are trusted in Windows Internet settings
#jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=trustedHosts
#
jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=disabled
```

Till jdk1.8.0_181 there was a default NTLM authentication callback which was useful in NTLM authentication process.

To run the above code with jdk1.8.0_181 onward, all you need is to set *jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth* for your java process.

Alternatively, you may set a JVM argument, e.g., `-Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=allHosts`, or set a system property, e.g., `System.setProperty("jdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth", "allHosts")`.

If you choose *trustedHosts*, make sure the URL is added in windows trusted site.

You can see this new system property used here during static init: `sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthentication`.

Further, you can see the setting is used here: `public static boolean NTLMAuthentication.isTrustedSite(URL)`

Finally, to programmatically control if a URL is trusted, you may install a callback.  See: `sun.net.www.protocol.http.ntlm.NTLMAuthenticationCallback`

Comment: Thank you.  I spent half a day debugging this issue.  NTLM is brutal outside of Win32!
Related: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225506 & https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/server-sent-http-status-code-401-unauthorized-error-when-using-java-based-functionality-caused-apar-ph19793

Comment: I know years past, but anyway, thank you very much