# Change in `url.openStream` behaviour in later Java 8 versions

Tags: java, url, java-8, stream, ntlm

I have a program that opens a file from our internal SVN by using

```
url.openStream();
```

on that url. This works fine with Java 7 and also with jdk1.8.0_161.

But, when I tried with the OpenJDK version jdk8u202-b08, I get

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: ...
```

Has the behaviour of `openStream` changed in later build versions of Java 8? If so, how can I solve this problem?

EDIT:

Additional tests showed that OpenJDK in version 8u192 works as well. So it must be a change between build version 192 and 202.

Comment: Can you try also with the latest release (u212-b04) https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html ? If it is a regression, maybe it has been fixed already.

Comment: 212 has the same problem. I checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague finally found out that there is a change in the default behaviour of the authentication. You can reverse this by using

```
java -Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=enabled -Djdk.http.ntlm.transparentAuth=trustedHosts
```

See also:

[How to provide ntlm authentication while calling any url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568189/how-to-provide-ntlm-authentication-while-calling-any-url)